# vba chart #n/a hide

Tags: excel, charts

this is a line chart:

`=SERIES("a",{43160,43161,43162,43163,43164},{3000,4000,#N/A,2000,4000},1)`

the point 2 is connected directly to point 4.

but i want to hide the segment near the point 3. that is, line segment 1: point 1 to point 2, and line segment 2: point 4 to point 5.

when i copy the data into excel cells, and delete the "#N/A", then draw the chart manually， it will get the right chart.

but the code above is generated by vba, and the final chart must contain all data, no cell ref.
how can i hide the "#n/a" in the chart?

Comment: Can  you add screenshot of  chart?

Comment: where is this data generated?  It needs error handling, to make it a zero or null.

Comment: this data is a slice of a data set,  which is generated from a vba API by "wind(a data service provider, like bloomberg)". i take a simplified piece for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jon Peltier has a solution on his site: [Another approach to plotting gaps in Excel charts](https://peltiertech.com/another-approach-plotting-gaps-excel-charts/) and [Plot Blank Cells and #N/A in Excel Charts](https://peltiertech.com/plot-blank-cells-na-in-excel-charts/)

The basics are to create a named range that references a blank cell if the populated cell contains an error.  It's a long formula as it needs to look at each value in turn.

With your data in cells `Sheet1!B1:B5` and `Sheet1!C1:C5` containing empty cells you'd create this named range:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!$B$1),Sheet1!$B$1,Sheet1!$C$1),IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!$B$2),Sheet1!$B$2,Sheet1!$C$2), IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!$B$3),Sheet1!$B$3,Sheet1!$C$3), IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!$B$4),Sheet1!$B$4,Sheet1!$C$4),IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!$B$5),Sheet1!$B$5,Sheet1!$C$5)
```

This checks if each cell contains a number, and if not it references the cell next to it instead.

Use the named range as your *Series values*: `=Book1!MySeries`.

If you're using Excel 2016 you can click on *Hidden and Empty Cells* in the *Select Data Source* dialog and tick **Show #N/A as an empty cell**.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all very much. the problem is solved.

```
.Format.Line.Visible = False
```

the data set can not be changed, but i can change the line segment formatting. when the gap in point 3 should show, i can change the point 4 's property to hide the line segment from 3 to 4.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote all about this in my tutorial [Plot Blank Cells and #N/A in Excel Charts](https://peltiertech.com/plot-blank-cells-na-in-excel-charts/), but here is the short version.

If you're using Office 365, or I think any version of Excel 2016, Microsoft has finally answered our pleas and given us a way to plot gaps in a chart, other than with actual blank cells. It works with #N/A, whether in a worksheet or hard-coded in the series formula.

Below I show your data in a range and in a chart (and you can't tell, but the chart actually uses your formula, not the worksheet range). If you have a recent enough version of Excel, right click on the chart and select Select Data from the pop-up menu. Then click the Hidden and Empty Cells button. In older versions of Excel, Empty meant totally empty, no value, no space character that looks empty, no formula that returns the null string "". But in the Hidden and Empty Cell Settings dialog, we can opt to show empty cells as blanks, which is the default, and also we can check a box to Show #N/A As an Empty Cell, which I think is also the default. The result is the chart with a gap in place of the #N/A value. Since these are the default settings, and you were asking the question, I suspect your version of Excel doesn't do this.

[image]